# Which is the best, clean way to join wire together

Tags: wire, cables, wiring

I am installing CCTV cameras and I'm using a 3A adapter to supply power to the cameras, but I have very messy results when trying to join together very small wires with electrical tape.

Is there any clean way of doing all this? For example, how can I join together the wires of 3 power supply cables? Also, how to join the Audio/Video lead to the normal wires? I find it very hard to first cut the A/V cable and then use electrical tape to join them.

I want to make something like [this](http://www.cctvcamerapros.com/CCTV-Cables-p/100vp.htm), but it's not as clean. It looks messy with electrical tape.

Comment: Wire nuts are another option, although they are usually used on and more appropriate for AC applications using thicker gauge wire.

Answer (score 9):

I would [solder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solder) the wires together and then use [heatshrink tubing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat-shrink_tubing) to cover the joint and help make things look neat and tidy.

Not sure how much you know, so I'll just keep going...

Solder is made to join electrical contacts, and it makes a durable bond. You need a [soldering iron](http://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=soldering%20iron#sugexp=chrome,mod=0&q=soldering%20iron&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbo=u&tbm=shop&source=og&sa=N&tab=wf&ei=NFjPT-i2K-OF6QHH1uGeDA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=eb5411c816233e83&biw=1280&bih=963) to heat solder. The basic approach is to hold the iron on the two (or more) wires to join, then apply solder to the heated joint. The solder will melt quickly and harden even faster after you take the iron off. That's a super basic description, and there's a ton of soldering tutorials around the web you can look to if you need help.

Heatshrink sounds like what you want if electric tape is "too messy". You basically cover the joined wires with it, then use hot air (via hot-air rework station, or just a hair drier) to shrink the tubing around the wires.

Comment: Don't forget to slide the heat shrink tubing over one of the wire ends *before* you solder the joint.  Unlike tape, you can't apply heat shrink tubing to a continuous wire.  (Despite this warning, I bet you'll forget at least once and have to open the joint and redo it).  That's never happened to me of course ;-)  No, I'd never do that...

Comment: I don't know if this is the accepted way of doing it, but when joining three wires, I find it easiest to solder two together first, then tin the third wire and solder it to the previous pair.  Yes, and put the shrink tube over either the pair of wires or single wire first!  I recommend the former because you'd hate to put shrink tube over the single wire, only to find that you can't slip it over the joint afterward!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go with @kevlar1818's answer. It's the cleanest and most reliable connection you can get. But if you're not the soldering type, you can use a butt splice crimp connector.

http://www.wiringproducts.com/contents/en-us/d47_butt_splice_connectors.html

Comment: Butt crimps can be quite good and are a valid way to do this, but you should note that you really need the right equipment to do them well.  If you're thinking squeezing with a vice or a pair of plyers, forget it and make a solder joint.  Butt crimps aren't for the average hobbyist.